# How to display an image in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am trying to make my first hamburger menu with some images, but they are displayed in grey scale, not the real image. Here is a photo of how it looks:

And here is the code for the XML file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/desp_mercedes"
    android:icon="@drawable/mercedes"
    android:title="Mercedes" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/desp_audi"
    android:icon="@drawable/audi"
    android:title="Audi" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/desp_bmw"
    android:icon="@drawable/bmw"
    android:title="BMW" />
```

I want to know how to display the original images. I have both SVG and PNG files for better quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to display the original images, here is the fragment of code:

```
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

"navigationView" is the name for my drawer, change it to yours on your MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

In your nav_header_main.xml layout resource file:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/nav_header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="160dp"
          android:background="@color/colorAccent"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:focusable="true"
          android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
```

//here you can add your image src

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_imageView"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_imageview" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Chike Mgbemena"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I mean, i want to display on the itemview the original images, instead of using android:icon, because it shows the images on grey-scale.

Comment: I don't think you can show the real color, but instead custom the tint

Comment: Add your image to drawable and use it like what I showed you here android:src="@drawable/ic_imageview" />

Comment: But that's not the image I want to change, I'm asking for the ones in gray, look on the photo, the ones in Mercedes, Audi, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try this out: [How do I customize the navigation drawer in Android Studios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100708/how-do-i-customize-the-navigation-drawer-in-android-studios/32104232#33886256)

TL;DR: Create a `ListView` in your `DrawerLayout` with the appropriate implementation, Adapter, item.xml and such.

Comment: And how do I create that Adapter?

Comment: You can look at the link and try out the 2 last answers.